# null source for FilterInputStream/FilterOutputStream

Tags: java, api, io

I'm writing classes work like [FilterInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) or [FilterOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html).

Looks like

```java
public FilterReadableByteChannel implements ReadableByteChannel {

    // Should I permit null for channel?
    public FilterReadableByteChannel(final ReadableByteChannel channel) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

And I found that both [FilterInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) and [FilterOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) permit `null` source.

```
 * @param   in   the underlying input stream, or <code>null</code> if
 *          this instance is to be created without an underlying stream.
```

Question:

1. Is there any practical reason for this?
2. Is there any possible case that changing the underlying source after created?

I know that `Why Not?` could be an answer, but I want to know if there were any reason why the original API designer did this.

Comment: You would have to have to ask the original API designer, if 'why not?' isn't adequate for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any practical reason for this?

Yes.  Even if not declared as such, classes `Filter*Stream` are conceptually abstract classes.  IOW, they only exist to be extended.  Subclasses could need to provide the `in` or `out` parameters after construction (example:  lazily; on first real use), and `Filter*Stream` gives them this flexibility.

> Is there any possible case that changing the underlying source after created?

The obvious case is when source is initially `null`.  Other cases that come to my mind are:
 1. Creating a subclass of `Filter*Stream` that acts as a selector.  IOW, has several underlying streams and methods to switch from one to the other.
 2. Creating a subclass of `FilterInputStream` that concatenates different `InputStream`s.
 3. Creating a subclass of `FilterOutputStream` that splits output into different `OutputStream`s.

> I know that Why Not? could be an answer, but I want to know if there were any reason why the original API designer did this.

Yes:  generality.